# Why is SonarLint downloading the same quality profile again and again?

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

We have a lot of plug-ins in our Eclipse project and we still want one quality profile for most of them. For maintenance reasons we did bind each plug-in to the same SonarQube project (xxx), so that we can batch update them if needed.
But still, for each plug-in I get:

```
Check for updates from server 'sonarxx' for project 'yy'
On project 'yy':
  - Quality profiles configuration changed
```

I would assume that once a quality profile is downloaded, SonarLint can apply it to all projects bound to that profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the quality profile is shared between projects. What is not is the information of which quality profile is used by which project. That's why you see this message.

But if you update all project bindings, you'll see that the costly WS call (api/rules) is made only once.

We could also detect that multiple Eclipse projects are bound to the same SQ project, and save some WS calls, but that should not save so much time. Also binding all Eclipse projects to the same SQ project is not good because you'll loose proper support of hiding remote issues marked as false positive/won't fix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have investigated it a little bit and found that the biggest issue was that it always makes a call for all the sub-projects. I dont get why it is doing that because it does not get extra information that it does not already have with the call of the parent project.

Comment: We did bind our projects now to the real projects on the server which means a lot more of maintenance. However it still takes a very long time to load eclipse.

I've added a follow-up question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920828/how-can-we-make-sonarlint-startup-faster-in-eclipse-with-lots-of-projects
(How can we improve the performance??)