# How can we make SonarLint startup faster in Eclipse with lots of projects?

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

In our case we had a parent project (trunk) where all plug-ins where sub-projects and we want all the sub projects to have the same rules. In order to make maintenance easier we thought we could bind all plug-in projects in eclipse to trunk (so we can just batch update them etc.). 
The problem here is that for some reason it always loads all sub projects for each project. 1) they are always the same 2) there is not more information in the call of the sub-project that the former call did not get.

If we bind each project to the real correct project in SonarLint that is a lot of effort. (we have hundreds of plug-ins.)
Still, for our 100+ plug-in projects that we have in Eclipse SonarLint takes some minutes to get all the info from the server.

How can we make SonarLint faster? Is there a recommended way? Can we help to improve the logic for this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

I think the title of your question is confusing. This is not about SonarLint startup, but about SonarLint "update all bindings" feature.

I have created a ticket that we will try to fix in the next version:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-200

Note that not binding Eclipse project to the correct SonarQube project/module will prevent correct match between local and remote issues. It means issues flagged as "won't fix" or "false positive" on SonarQube side will not be muted in Eclipse.

You said mapping many projects is tedious. What about the auto-bind feature? If it is failing to correctly guess binding between local and remote projects, I encourage you to open a thread on the [SonarLint Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/sonarlint) to so that we can investigate the reason.

Comment: In our case it IS matching local and remote issues correctly. because all our projects are sub projects of the one we bound it to. So there was no problem here. It is matching absolutely correctly.

Comment: Also with the auto-bind it is still tedious because there is no "auto-bind all" so I have to open the dialog 200 times. And then SonarLint might change the place where they store that (like they already did) and you have to do it all over again.

Comment: Thanks for opening a ticket. We will help where we can if you need someone to find out more information or test things.

Comment: There is "auto-bind all". Just select as many projects as you want, right click -> bind.